# Is it possible to let users create and perform database migrations from a form?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

Can you take form data and change database schema? Is it a good idea? Is there a downside to many migrations from a 'default' database?

---

I want users to be able to add / remove tables, columns, and rows.  Making schema changes requires migrations, so adding in that functionality would require writing a view that takes form data and inserts it into a function that then uses Flask-Migrate.

If I manage to build this, don't migrations build the required separate scripts and everything that goes along with that each time something is added or removed? Is that practical for something like this, where 10 or 20 new tables might be added to the starting database?

If I allow users to add columns to a table, it will have to modify the table's class. Is that possible, or a safe idea?  If not, I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out, and at least get me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typical web application, the deployed database does not change its schema at runtime. The schema is only changed during an upgrade, and only the developers make these changes. Operations that users perform on the application can add, remove or modify rows, but not modify the tables or columns themselves.

If you need to offer your users a way to add flexible data structures, then you should design your database schema in a way that this is possible. For example, if you wanted your users to add custom key/value pairs, you could have a table with columns `user_id`, `key_name` and `value`. You may also want to investigate if a schema-less database fits your needs better.